# Hide pagination button in CListView but donot disable them

Tags: yii, yii-components

I am using yii framework. I want to hide pagination button of CListView widget but not disable them so that i can automatically trigger the request for next page by clicking them via javascript when user finish processing the list items. I tried enablePagination=>false but it remove the links to next pages too. I tried to hide them through javascript onLoad. Its working fine but in case the page load slowly I can see the pagination button.
Is there some standard way to hide them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **pagerCssClass** property of CListView to define separate class for pagination button if i am getting your problem right.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                    'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
                    'pagerCssClass'=>'hideButton',
        ));
```

**CSS**

```
   .hideButton{
    display:none;
    }
```